# Why Laplace Transform of 1 and u(t) are the same.

Tags: laplace-transform, step-function

I looked at the Laplace Transform Table on the Internet and I saw that Laplace Transform of step function is equal to laplace transform of 1 .Is it because the region of convergence of the Laplace transform of 1 or what?

Secondly Why does the Laplace transform of u(t) not  have impulsive term?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $u(t)=
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } t\geq 0\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
The laplace transform of a function $f$:
$$F(s):=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$
And in the domain $t \in [0,\infty)$ both the $f(t)=1$ and $u(t)$ equals to $1$.